# Как реализовать изменение значений в полях в реальном времени (тег select)?

Tags: python, html, django, select

Разрабатываю одно приложение на Django.
БД имеется.

Есть форма, в которой 3 поля (каждое из них - это `select`).

Выглядит она вот так:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:index' %}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="country">
      {% for country in countries %}
        <option>{{ country }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="league">
      {% for ountry in countries %}
        <option>{{ country }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="team">
      {% for country in countries %}
        <option>{{ country }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Сейчас там просто 3 поля с выбором страны.

Я хочу реализовать следующее:

> При выборе страны в первом поле, во втором появляются только элементы
> принадлежащие к этой стране, а в третьем поле уже элементы
> принадлежащие только к элементу из второго поля. Таким образом
> выбирается один конкретный элемент.

Я примерно понимаю, что должно происходить в бэкенде. По значению из первого поля данные в базе фильтруются и передаются во второе поле, после - такая же процедура, только уже со вторым и третьим полями.

А вот как это реализовать так, чтобы значения в полях менялись, так сказать, в реальном времени - не понимаю.

Буду рад любым ответам и идеям.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно подписатся на событие `onchange` у первого и второго `select`. и вызывать вде функции. По смене первого (выборе страны), получать его значение и отправлять ajax запрос на сервер, сервер должен будет прислать нужные данные для второго `select`. Для их отображения можно сделать:

```
select2.innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < response; i++) {
    select2.innerHTML += <option>response[i]</option>;
}
```

*response - переменная с данными из ajax.

Таким образом, первым действием `select2.innerHTML = "";` очищается все.
А циклом добавляются новые значения.